# Install Web2py in virtual hosting

Tags: apache2, wsgi, web2py

Install Web2py by a script setup-web2py-ubuntu.sh, previously adjusted the way for their virtual hosting.
But it works only on port 443, and the 80 th issue

> It works!

How to fix?

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
#NameVirtualHost *:443
# If the WSGIDaemonProcess directive is specified outside of all virtual
# host containers, any WSGI application can be delegated to be run within
# that daemon process group.
# If the WSGIDaemonProcess directive is specified
# within a virtual host container, only WSGI applications associated with
# virtual hosts with the same server name as that virtual host can be
# delegated to that set of daemon processes.
WSGIDaemonProcess demo2.host.ru user=web2 group=client1

<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIProcessGroup demo2.host.ru
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*) \
        /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Options -Indexes
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  <Location /admin>
  Deny from all
  </Location>

  <LocationMatch ^/([^/]+)/appadmin>
  Deny from all
  </LocationMatch>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/ssl/ispserver.key
WSGIProcessGroup demo2.host.ru
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/wsgihandler.py
  WSGIPassAuthorization On

  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py>
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
    <Files wsgihandler.py>
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  AliasMatch ^/([^/]+)/static/(.*) \
        /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/applications/$1/static/$2

  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web2/web/web2py/applications/*/static/>
    Options -Indexes
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hour"
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Create files: parameters_443.py and parameters_80.py in folder web2py.

```
password="pbkdf2(1000,20,sha512)$851a015489"
```

Still not working...
Plz help! :'(